# How to skip lines / how to execute one if statements and skip the rest of them if I have multiple if statement

Tags: batch-file

I need to detect if the file is empty or not. If the file is empty do something; otherwise, do something else.

In order to reach this goal, I use if statement inside of for loop. By the way how I created my script, it works only when the file is not empty

Problem: If there is no data inside of test.txt file, the batch files will read both :fault and :true. I tried to skip the true condition by "skip = 5", but I it failed. I figured I wrote the skip statement incorrectly.

What I want: If test.txt has data, :true would be executed; If the test.txt don't contain any data, :fault would be executed. Echo statements would be executed after either :fault condition or :true condition.

```
for %%f in (test*.txt) do 
    if %%~zf EQU 0 goto fault
    if %%~zf NEQ 0 goto true

:fault
Copy C:\Main\Test\final*.txt C:\Main\Test\final\* /y
REM Goto skip =5   

:true
Copy C:\Main\Test\final*.txt C:\Main\Test\final\* /y
Copy C:\Main\Test\semfinal*.txt C:\Main\Test\semfinal\* /y

echo....
echo....
```

Answer (score 1):

`skip=..` is a `FOR /F` option and will do nothing with `IF` (have on mind also that there are missing brackets in your code) .And `GOTO` breaks `for` context so it will be executed only over the first file. You can use another `GOTO` at the end of each section - in case you want to process only one file.

```
for %%f in (test*.txt) do (
    if %%~zf EQU 0 goto fault
    if %%~zf NEQ 0 goto true
)
:fault
Copy C:\Main\Test\final*.txt C:\Main\Test\final\* /y

goto :end_if

:true
Copy C:\Main\Test\final*.txt C:\Main\Test\final\* /y
Copy C:\Main\Test\semfinal*.txt C:\Main\Test\semfinal\* /y

goto :end_if


:end_if
echo....
echo....
```

or you can put your expressions in brackets as `GOTO` decreases the performance  and you'll process all files that apply to the mask.

```
for %%f in (test*.txt) do (
    if %%~zf EQU 0 (
        Copy C:\Main\Test\final*.txt C:\Main\Test\final\* /y
    ) else (
        Copy C:\Main\Test\final*.txt C:\Main\Test\final\* /y
        Copy C:\Main\Test\semfinal*.txt C:\Main\Test\semfinal\* /y
    )
)
```

Comment: thank you npocmaka for the detail explanation. When I researched on for & if statement, some people said we could not use else statement. Could you please advise on when we could not use else statement?

Comment: I tried the if else statement, but the system is not reading anything inside of for do. Do you have any idea on what the reason is?

Comment: system would read the if statement, only when I wrote the if statement right after do..could you please advise on the reason of it? would space or new line break my script in batch?

Comment: @baciyan `else` spends you a little bit code.Of course you can you two if statements.You can put `echo some test message` in each if/else section to check it its reached.